# SSH config regexp aliases

Tags: ssh, alias, wildcards

I am looking for a way to specify aliases in `.ssh/config` that would replace a cumbersome config like this:

```
Host zeus-1
  HostName zeus-XXX-YYY-001.ZZZ

...

Host zeus-999
  HostName zeus-XXX-YYY-999.ZZZ
```

in some easier to maintain way, preferebly some kind of a wildcard.

============

NOTE:

I understand that I could make use of `%h` variable in `.ssh/config` if I wanted to connect to a machine `zeus-001.XXX-YYY.ZZZ`

```
Host zeus-*
  HostName %h.XXX-YYY.ZZZ
```

Which is **not** very usable in this case, thanks to very long hostnames.

Is there a way to achieve such behaviour in `.ssh/config` ?

Comment: Are you using `bash`? read the output of `help alias`

Comment: More info on bash: https://tldp.org/ > Bash guides, or even `man bash`